# How to convert WordPress xml backup to yaml?

Tags: xml, wordpress, yaml

WordPress xlm is the only format available.

Even if we can import it imperfectly and then clean it up manually this would also be a big help.

Comment: Please, check the small guides [About] and [ask]. Welcome to [so] and note the sister site [wordpress.se].

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used exitwp to convert Wordpress XML to YAML header and Markdown body for each post.  It was quite accurate.

That will get you most of the way there.  IMHO, Markdown may be more manageable for post bodies than YAML.

https://github.com/thomasf/exitwp